# Windows 2008 R2 Unattended installation example?

Tags: windows-server-2008, automation, unattended

In following-up another [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/31212/perform-an-unattended-install-of-windows-server-2008), are there any sources of reliable (ie, "just works") unattended response files for Windows 2008 R2 x64 available for modification, or do you have to start with the [WAIK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=C7D4BC6D-15F3-4284-9123-679830D629F2)?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by an "it just works" unattend response file?

Comment: ie - one that's known to deploy, doesn't need any special tweaking beyond license key

Comment: so you don't need any networking config, server name generation etc?

Comment: @Jim B - dhcp is fine, I'm just looking for a bare-bones one to start from

Comment: If you plan on making an changes to a working autounattend then I would suggest you just make the changes via windows SIM (which would also create a new unattend if you don't already have one).  I can post an unattend file but it would take longer for you to modify it than it would for you to make your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WAIK contains a utility called windows SIM that will create autounattend.xml files (based on the answers you give it ) as well as build the deploy media if you so choose.  For a virtual environment I would recommend not manually installing machines and would suggest setting up WDS (with or without MDT) to create custom server or workstation installs on the fly.  Since the tools build all of the unattend files (plus have the ability to customize the OS) its generally worth the small time investment even if its just for a lab